# C, проблема с циклом в подсчёте суммы

Tags: c

Дано: [image: Бесконечная сумма]

При х:=0.2

Это выражение нужно вычислить с точностью до n знаков после запятой.
Без цикла выражение правильно /кажется/ считается один раз. Как только добавляется любой вид цикла - этот цикл становится бесконечным.
Что тут не так?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main()
{
    int n = 1;
    float x = 0.2, S = 0, eps = 0.0001;
    while (((pow((1 + x), (2 * n)) / (float)n) > eps) && (n < INT_MAX)) {
        S += pow(-1,n)*(pow((1 +x), (2 * n)) / (float)n);
        n++;
    }
    printf("%f", S);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Ым... Но при `x = 0.2` значение `pow(1 + x, 2 * n) / n` будет только расти с ростом `n` (после небольшого изначального падения). Оно никогда не станет меньше `eps`, т.е. при ваших условиях, разумеется, получается бесконечный цикл. Почему вас это удивляет?

Comment: Считать сумму расходящегося знакопеременного ряда, да ещё с заданной точностью? да ваш преподаватель эстет, аднака.

Comment: Ты бы просто ради прикола, поставил значения вместо n разные: 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 100, 1000. И посмотри как оно меняется. Я в математике сам дуб, но что-то мне не нравится, что точность вычисляется таким образом. Обычно ведь точность, это разница между двумя результатами вычисления. И используй double вместо float лучуше, можно даже long double.

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что внизу не пропущен восклицательный знак? Не `n!` в знаменателе? В том виде, что приведен, ряд сходится при `-2 <=x <= 0`...